# Buttons on UIScrollView bounces back when centered

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

My UIScrollView bounces back from left side, but stays normal from the right side.
Look at the gif please.

[image: dragging]

Important note: The buttons should be centered when the screen opens.

To center my buttons, I create them like this:

```
button.frame = CGRect(
                x: screenWidth/2 + gap,
                y: 0,
                width: buttonWidth,
                height: buttonHeight)
buttonsScrollView.addSubview(button)
```

I already set wide content size

```
buttonsScrollView.contentSize.width = screenWidth
```

and adding extra space - `screenWidth + 100` does not help, it makes wider only from the right side.

Comment: Need to see how and where you set the value for screenWidth. Also share the full code of the creation of buttons which I believe is in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "calculated" frames or with auto-layout. In either case, the general idea...

Add your buttons to a `UIView` - we'll call it `buttonsView`:

[image]

Start the first button at `gap` distance from Zero, and set the frame of `buttonsView` to the height of the buttons, and add `gap` distance to the right-end.

Add `buttonsView` to the scroll view, at `x: 0, y: 0`.

Set the scroll view's `.contentSize = buttonsView.frame.size`.

Do all of that in `viewDidLoad()`.

We can't center the `buttonsView` until we know the scroll view's frame width, which will likely vary depending on device (and if you rotate the device), so...

Add a class property to track the scroll view's width:

```
// track the scroll view frame width
var scrollViewWidth: CGFloat = 0
```

then, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` we know the scroll view's frame, so we'll adjust the `.contentOffset.x` to horizontally center the `buttonsView`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    // here we know frame size, but
    //  viewDidLayoutSubviews() can (and usually will) be called multiple times
    //  so we only want to execute this code when the scroll view width changes
    if scrollViewWidth != scrollView.frame.width {
        scrollViewWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        
        // calculate content offset x so the row of buttons is centered horizontally
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = (buttonsView.frame.width - scrollView.frame.width) * 0.5
    }
    
}
```

Here's a complete sample implementation. No `@IBOutlet` connections -- everything is done via code -- so just set a view controller's class to `CenterScrollViewController`:

```
class CenterScrollViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // create a scroll view
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        // background color so we can see its frame
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    
    // create a buttons holder view
    let buttonsView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        return v
    }()
    
    // gap between buttons and on left/right sides of button row
    let gap: CGFloat = 12
    
    // buttons will be (round) at 44 x 44 points
    let btnSize: CGFloat = 44
    
    // number of buttons
    let numButtons: Int = 9
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        title = "Calc"
        
        // add scroll view to view
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // add buttons view to scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(buttonsView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scroll view
            //  Top + 40
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            // Leading and Trailing
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            // Height equal to button height + "padding" on bottom
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btnSize + gap),
            
        ])
        
        // let's add some buttons to the buttons view
        var x: CGFloat = gap
        for i in 1...numButtons {
            let b = UIButton()
            b.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            b.setTitle("\(i)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            
            // let's keep the buttons square (1:1 ratio) so we can make them round
            b.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: btnSize, height: btnSize)
            
            b.layer.cornerRadius = btnSize * 0.5
            b.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            b.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            buttonsView.addSubview(b)
            
            x += btnSize + gap
        }
        
        // x now equals the total buttons width plus gap on each side
        // so set the frame size of the buttons view to (x, btnSize)
        buttonsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: x, height: btnSize)
    
        // set scroll view content size to the size of the buttons view
        scrollView.contentSize = buttonsView.frame.size
    }
    
    // track the scroll view frame width
    var scrollViewWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // here we know frame size, but
        //  viewDidLayoutSubviews() can (and usually will) be called multiple times
        //  so we only want to execute this code when the scroll view width changes
        if scrollViewWidth != scrollView.frame.width {
            scrollViewWidth = scrollView.frame.width
            
            // calculate content offset x so the row of buttons is centered horizontally
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = (buttonsView.frame.width - scrollView.frame.width) * 0.5
        }
        
    }
    
}
```